# Directive can't use data resolved by a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Consider the initial app **`main`** state:

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '',
    views: {
        'nav@': {
            templateUrl: baseTemplatesUrl + 'nav.main.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            controller: 'mainNavController',
            resolve: {
                timelinesService: 'timelinesService'
            }
        },
        'content@': {
            template: ''
        }
    }
});
```

Inside the **nav.main.html** template I'm trying to use a simple **slider directive**:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="t in vm.timelines">
  <!-- ui-sref=".timeline({yearFrom: t.yearFrom, yearTo: t.yearTo})" -->
  <a class="button tiny" ui-sref-active="active">{{t.text}}</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<div simple-slider items="vm.timelines" on-item-clicked="vm.timelineClicked"></div>
```

The directive is defined as:

```
function simpleSlider() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: baseTemplatesUrl + 'directive.simpleSlider.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            onItemClicked: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.curIndex = 0;
            scope.next = function() {
                scope.curIndex < scope.items.length - 1 ? scope.curIndex++ : scope.curIndex = 0;
            };
            scope.prev = function() {
                scope.curIndex > 0 ? scope.curIndex-- : scope.curIndex = scope.items.length - 1;
            };
            scope.$watch('curIndex', function() {                    
                scope.items.forEach(function(item) {
                    item.active = false;
                });
                scope.items[scope.curIndex].active = true;
            });
        },
    };
}
```

**The problem**

On a page load the directive's `$watch` throws an exception saying that **`scope.items[scope.curIndex]`** is **undefined**, whereas the **`ng-repeat="t in vm.timelines"`** inside the **nav.main.html** template renders successfully.

Why **the watch** fails / how to pass **`vm.timelines`** to directive's scope?

**The fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/challenger/Le5p9aup/

**Update 1. Regarding @Lex answer**

The fiddle is working. But my setup differs from the given fiddle. In my setup the **`timelinesService`** returns the **$http promise**:

```
var service = {
    getTimelines: function() {
        return $http.get('/api/timelines');
    }
};
```

then inside the **`navMainController`** the **`vm.timelines`** array gets populated:

```
vm.timelines = []; 
timelinesService.getTimelines().then(function(response) {
    vm.timelines = response.data.timelines;
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Then, unless you click the directive's prev/next button, the $watch will fail:

```
// scope.items[scope.curIndex] is undefined
scope.items[scope.curIndex].active = true;
```

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate the issue with your JSFiddle. It all works. I even added a property on your controller that contains the currently selected timeline and set the value from within the directive. [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Le5p9aup/46/)

Comment: @Lex yes, the fiddle is working. Please, see the update.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. So the `link` in your directive is executing before your promise has resolved. Try this, change your `<div>` using the directive to `<div simple-slider items="vm.timelines" on-item-clicked="vm.timelineClicked" ng-if="vm.timelines"></div>`. By including the `ng-if` it should cause that `<div>` not to render until you actually have data in `vm.timelines` which should keep the directive's `link` from executing until it has something to watch.

Comment: @Lex yes that helps! It also can be resolved by placing **`link's`** body into internal function, by calling the function using **`$timeout`**.

Comment: @Lex if you provide an answer I'll accept it. Thank you and God bless you in Jesus name:)

Comment: I think the `$timeout` solution is better because that avoids `ng-if` which will be re-evaluated with every digest cycle.

Comment: @Lex thank you one more time, this is a good point!